# Can Kinesis Firehose do filtering?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-kinesis-firehose

So we have 100 different types of messages coming into our Kinesis stream.  We only want to save 4 types.  I know Kinesis can **transform** messages, but can it **filter** as well?  How is this done?

Comment: A few clarification questions:

1. What's the source of the data? 
2. is this a kinesis firehose or kinesis data stream?
3. Any reason you can't filter at the source?

Comment: 1. The source is a Kinesis Data Stream.  2.  This is a Firehose that I am using.  3.  No, we want to pick off specific types of messages for customers.  There might be a lot of these.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Filtering is just a transform in which you decide not to output anything. You indicate this by sending the result with a value `"Dropped"` as per [the documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/firehose/latest/dev/data-transformation.html).

You can find at [this post](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/amazon-kinesis-firehose-data-transformation-with-aws-lambda/) an example of transform, and the logic includes several things: letting records just pass through without any transform (status `"OK"`), transforming and outputting a record (again, status `"OK"`), dropping -or filtering- a record (status `"Dropped"`), and communicating an error using the status `"ProcessingFailed"`